# Адаптивность в jquery

Tags: jquery

Например есть такой плагин mmenu, как сделать чтобы он срабатывал только на определенной ширине экрана? подобно медиа запросам в css нашла вот такое решение

```
$(window).on('resize', function () { 
 if ($(window).width() > 1280) { 
        // код 
  } else { 
        // код 
  } 
})
```

но проблема в том, что если оно сработало один раз на узком экране и я экран расширю после этого, то действие плагина так и сохранится, а мне надо чтобы при расширении экрана плагин не применялся
Может есть какие-то другие методы достичь? или надо через else отменять действие плагина, если да, то какой командой?

Хотелось бы получить универсальный шаблон, который позволяет сделать jquery таким же адаптивным как css. Или вообще узнать как данная проблема решается

Comment: Не понятно в чем именно проблема... Все прекрасно работает...

Comment: Но а если быть откровенным. если нет особой надобности, такое лучше уж на `css` реализовать... Не надо делать с помощью `js`, то с чем `css` прекрасно справляется

Comment: А просто скрывать меню в зависимости от медиа запроса не вариант? Как оно у вас вообще реализовано? добавьте код

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1280) {
    $('body').css({"background":"red"})
  } else {
    $('body').css({"background":"blue"})
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Добавьте чуточку CSS для наглядности) Мелоч, а приятно)

Comment: @meine, а какой смысл, все равно ее `jq` интересует..)))  Я бы лучше это в `css` реализовал